# Deleting sentences in database file

Tags: anti-virus, database, md5, hashing

I'm writing a MD5 based antivirus, and my friend send to me a document with thousands of samples and their MD5. All is fine, but I have to delete all sentences what contain "File does not exists:" along with the short numbers between Virus name and the MD5 hash.

How can I accomplish this?

[image: Screen of problem]:

Comment: You should mention, which db do you use.

Comment: since you appear to be using NPP, I would use regular expressions with the Find/Replace feature. the "File Does Not Exist" error is easy enough to replace, and the number column appears to have a predictable number of whitespace characters on either side, so you can match that with a pattern and replace them with "".